# Problema con la función de auto completar de chrome

Tags: html, jquery, html5, google-chrome, chrome

mi problema es que tengo un automplete con jQuery y todo funciona bien el problema es en producción que se genera el listado que utiliza Chrome se posiciona por encima de mi listado les dejo una foto de mi problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabrá como desactivar esto?

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar el código con el cual haces el autocomplete? Ayudaría mucho para saber si es posible en el formulario colocar la la opción autocomplete= off

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza el atributo `autocomplete`.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="campo" autocomplete="off">
```

Te dejo un [enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp) con mas informacion.

Comment: Ya lo realice y no dio resultado

Comment: que libreria de jquery para el autocompletado estas utilizando. Tienes el explorador actualizado.